# Basic measure theory question, if there exists a set such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ then $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ - answer check

Tags: measure-theory

Basic measure theory question, if there exists a set such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ then $\mu(\emptyset)=0$

If $\mu$ is an extended real valued, non-negative, additive, set function defined on a ring R such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ for at least one $E$ in $R$ then $\mu(\emptyset)=0$

My "solution"

Well $E\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$ and $E\cup\emptyset=E\in R$, so I can use additivity.

$\mu(E\cup\emptyset)=\mu(E)+\mu(\emptyset)$

BUT! $\mu(E\cup\emptyset)=\mu(E)$

So $\mu(E)=\mu(E)-\mu(\emptyset)$

Thus $\mu(\emptyset)=0$

**Why I do not like this:**

It doesn't break if $\mu(E)=\infty$, I don't even have to "argue" $\infty-\infty=0$ to break it (I would never subtract infinity like this, the point is this isn't the flaw in my logic) - perhaps this is the flaw, does $x-x=0$ breakdown when $x=\infty$?

Anyway, I don't use the given information. Also I could define $\mu=\infty$ always. It wouldn't be a measure, but I could.

I need to show that if I have one set of finite measure that the nullset has measure of 0. USING Additivity.

**Addendum**
I cannot see any other way to go about it

Comment: What do you mean by $E$ in $R$, do you mean open set $E$ in a topology on $R$?

Comment: @EnjoysMath do you know what a ring is (not in algebra terms but as in "thing that is closed under union and set-subtraction")

Comment: Typically $\infty - \infty$ *is* undefined, hence the argument fails for $E$ with infinite measure.

Comment: @Jon so the argument relies on $\mu(E)-\mu(E)$ being undefined? (I'm not sure of the structure of the extended reals - evidently, I take it the whole "everything has an additive inverse" thing stops?)

Comment: Ask whether "every set has infinite measure" (including the empty set) is possible.

Comment: @GEdgar it is totally possible to have a /function/ on a /ring/ with that property, here $\mu$ doesn't have to be a measure, the hypothesis is "additive + one set of finite mu-ness $\implies$ null-set has mu-ness of 0" - notice I've used "mu-ness" not "measure" to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AlecTeal Essentially.  If you identify $\mu(E) - \mu(E)$ with $\mu(\varnothing)$ then the left-hand side had better have a value.  This is why we need a set of finite measure.

Comment: @Jon so the extended real numbers (as in the algebraic field) - everything is fine except infinity - right? So everything has an additive inverse, EXCEPT infinity (this may sound silly but I was viewing (am viewing) the extended real numbers as $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$)

Comment: @AlecTeal $\infty - \infty$ is a no-no.  Everything else is defined how you'd expect.  Your book should have a section somewhere outlining what operations can and cannot be performed in the extended reals.

Comment: Correct, we want $(+\infty) + (+\infty) = (+\infty)$, which is not compatible with existence of an additive inverse, and additive identity zero.

Comment: @Jon brilliant, thanks. Just to defend my stupidity, I was trying to ignore "infinity" and just imagine bolting on two things to the real numbers, declaring one bigger than everything and the other smaller. The book isn't clear on what structure carries forward. So I'd tried to impose $x-x=0$ for any x in the real numbers, with these two extra symbols. So to take from this, $x-x=0$ is wrong (here) I should write $x-x=0$ provided $x\ne\infty$ right?

Comment: @GEdgar I should have been a little more thoughtful. I was trying to bolt on 2 more objects (and sidestep dealing with infinity) to the real numbers, but that example you just gave (which the book does give) means - as you say - additive inverse is out of the window. Thanks for your help! BTW IF YOU POST AN ANSWER I WILL GIVE CREDIT!

Comment: @AlecTeal That'll work.  And if there's still any doubt, GEdgar's analysis pretty much spells out why we can't have both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as candidates for a measure.

Comment: It did, thanks for your time @Jon, if you post a short answer I will give you credit as you did help me! Thanks. Now I've seen my mistake, which means I can be confident (rather than trying to deduce it from the question).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, there is no additive inverse for $+\infty$ or for $-\infty$ in the extended reals.  Indeed, we want $(+\infty)+(+\infty) = (+\infty)$, but an addive inverse would let us subtract $(+\infty)$ from both sides to conclude $(+\infty) = 0$.

Why do we want $(+\infty)+(+\infty) = (+\infty)$?  For example, in the real line with Lebesgue measure,  the two unbounded intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,+\infty)$ both have measure $+\infty$, and so does their disjoint union.

Incidentally: for the extended reals there is a more controversial convention: $0 \cdot (+\infty) = 0 = 0 \cdot (-\infty$).